# Difference between a4j:commandLink and h:commandLink

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Title says everything.

What is the difference between a4j:commandLink and h:commandLink?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From richfaces docs

> The `<a4j:commandLink>` component is
>   very similar to the `<h:commandLink>`
>   component, the only difference is that
>   an Ajax form submit is generated on a
>   click and it allows dynamic
>   rerendering after a response comes
>   back. It's not necessary to plug any
>   support into the component, as Ajax
>   support is already built in.

More info about h:commandLink [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/h/commandLink.html) and a4j [here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_commandLink.html).

Read both and you will be able to make your own conclusions.

Comment: Note that the OP has tagged JSF 2.0.