# Difference between a4j:commandButton and h:commandButton

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

What is the difference between `a4j:commandButton` and `h:commandButton`?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between a4j:commandLink and h:commandLink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018887/difference-between-a4jcommandlink-and-hcommandlink). As noted by BalusC in comments of the answer, answer is for jsf-1.2

Answer (score 1):

You can read the `a4j:commandButton` documentation [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?c=commandButton&tab=usage)

Following an extract of documentation:

**a4j:commandButton is similar to the standard h:commandButton, but produces an Ajax request with a further partial page update. 'reRender' attribute points to the component(s) that should be re-rendered in the component tree and updated in the browser DOM after an Ajax Response is completed.**